# Updating table using another table's value multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, updates

To me this is a simple question, but one that I have been searching for days for and have not found the appropriate solution.

I have three tables. One for contacts, one for states, and one for yes/no questions. The contacts table is the primary table that refers to the other two tables for values for certain fields. The yes/no table is referred to three times in the contacts table. The states table is referred to once.

I have been able to code the insert php files with no problems with the appropriate select box that shows the values from the states and yes/no tables and inserts the values into the contacts table.

The issue I am having is on the update php files. I have not been able to find examples of code that would work for using the yes/no table multiple times to update fields in the contacts table.

I am using the current version of xampp with the current versions of php and mysql. I am coding using PDO as the connection to mysql.

Here is the current update mysql code ( I know there needs to be a connection made to the states and yesno tables, I just do not know what it should be.)

```html
<?php

require '../app/start.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $deceased = $_POST['deceased'];
    $active = $_POST['active'];
    $realname = $_POST['realname'];
    $slug = $_POST['slug'];
    $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
    $prefernick = $_POST['prefernick'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $statelookup = $_POST['statelookup'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $emailtwo = $_POST['emailtwo'];
    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];

    $updatePage = $db ->prepare("
        UPDATE contacts
        SET
            deceased = :deceased,
            active = :active,
            realname = :realname,
            slug = :slug,
            nickname = :nickname,
            prefernick = :prefernick,
            dob = :dob,
            address = :address,
            city = :city,
            statelookup = :statelookup,
            zipcode = :zipcode,
            phone = :phone,
            email = :email,
            emailtwo = :emailtwo,
            facebook = :facebook,
            twitter = :twitter,
            updated = NOW()
        WHERE id = :id
    ");

    $updatePage->execute([
        'id' => $id,
        'deceased' => $deceased,
        'active' => $active,
        'realname' => $realname,
        'slug' => $slug,
        'nickname' => $nickname,
        'prefernick' => $prefernick,
        'dob' => $dob,
        'address' => $address,
        'city' => $city,
        'statelookup' => $statelookup,
        'zipcode' => $zipcode,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'email' => $email,
        'emailtwo' => $emailtwo,
        'facebook' => $facebook,
        'twitter' => $twitter,
    ]);

    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/adminix/list-contacts.php');
}

if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/adminix/list-contacts.php');
        die();
}

$page = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM contacts
    WHERE id = :id
");

$page->execute(['id' => $_GET['id']]);

$page = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

require VIEW_ROOT . '/adminix/edit-contacts.php';
```

Here is the current update php code and form ( I know there needs to be a change to the select options, I just do not know what it should be to pull the existing value from the contacts table, but also show the available options from either the states table or yesno table.)

```html
<?php require VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/header.php'; ?>

<?php
// Require SQL Look-ups

$yesno1 = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM yesno
    ORDER BY yesno_id DESC
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$yesno2 = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM yesno
    ORDER BY yesno_id ASC
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$states = $db->query("
    SELECT *
    FROM states
    ORDER BY states_id DESC
")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

    <h2>EDIT CONTACTS PAGE</h2>

    <form action="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/adminix/edit-contacts.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">

        <table width="100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="deceased">
                        Deceased:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="deceased" id="deceased">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($yesno1 as $rowone) {
                            print '<option selected="'.$page['deceased'].'">'.$rowone['yesno'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="active">
                        Active:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="active" id="active">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($yesno2 as $rowtwo) {
                            print '<option value="'.$rowtwo['yesno_id'].'">'.$rowtwo['yesno'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="realname">
                        Real Name:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="realname" id="realname" value="<?php echo escape($page['realname']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="slug">
                        Slug:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="slug" id="slug" value="<?php echo escape($page['slug']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="nickname">
                        Nick Name:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="<?php echo escape($page['nickname']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="prefernick">
                        Prefer Nick Name:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="prefernick" id="prefernick">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($yesno2 as $rowthree) {
                            print '<option value="'.$rowthree['yesno_id'].'">'.$rowthree['yesno'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="dob">
                        Date of Birth:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"  value="<?php echo escape($page['dob']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="address">
                        Address:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address"  value="<?php echo escape($page['address']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="city">
                        City:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city"  value="<?php echo escape($page['city']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="statelookup">
                        State:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="statelookup" id="statelookup">
                        <?php
                        foreach ($states as $rowfour) {
                            print '<option value="'.$rowfour['states_id'].'">'.$rowfour['state_lookup'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="zipcode">
                        Zip Code:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode"  value="<?php echo escape($page['zipcode']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="phone">
                        Phone:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"  value="<?php echo escape($page['phone']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="email">
                        Email:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value="<?php echo escape($page['email']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="emailtwo">
                        Email Two
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="emailtwo" id="emailtwo"  value="<?php echo escape($page['emailtwo']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="facebook">
                        Facebook:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="facebook" id="facebook"  value="<?php echo escape($page['facebook']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="twitter">
                        Twitter:
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter"  value="<?php echo escape($page['twitter']); ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo escape($page['id']) ?>">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Edited Contact">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

<?php require VIEW_ROOT . '/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

The yesno table has two fields, yesno_id and yesno and the values of the yesno field are Yes and No. The states table has twofields, states_id and state_lookup and a list of the fifty U.S. States.

Any assistance that can be offered would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to shorten this to get to the meat of the problem? It's difficult to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Absolutely, what I am having difficulties with is showing the value of field "deceased" that is linked to the id the yesno table but also showing the other values to update it with. So if the value of "deceased" is 1 and the corresponding id in the yesno table for 1 is yes, then on the update form, I want to show the yes, but have a dropdown showing the other options in case a change needs to be made. @dlporter98

Comment: The issue is that I use the yesno table values in three of the fields in the contacts table, so it is causing errors when I try to use the single field solutions I found online. @dlporter98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand. The structure of the yesno table is insufficient for your needs. In fact, I would suggest that you not use that table at all. Instead change the column types of 'deceased' and 'prefernick' to an [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

```
deceased ENUM('Yes', 'No')
prefernick ENUM('Yes', 'NO')
```

Then in you html

```
<select name="deceased" id="deceased">
<option <?php echo $page['deceased'] === 'Yes' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php echo $page['deceased'] === 'No' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Be sure to do the same with the 'prefernick' select as well.

In your PHP:

```
   //You forgot to prefix the keys with colons.
   $updatePage->execute([
        ':id' => $id,
        ':deceased' => $deceased,
        ':active' => $active,
        ':realname' => $realname,
        ':slug' => $slug,
        ':nickname' => $nickname,
        ':prefernick' => $prefernick,
        ':dob' => $dob,
        ':address' => $address,
        ':city' => $city,
        ':statelookup' => $statelookup,
        ':zipcode' => $zipcode,
        ':phone' => $phone,
        ':email' => $email,
        ':emailtwo' => $emailtwo,
        ':facebook' => $facebook,
        ':twitter' => $twitter,
    ]);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I was not aware of the ENUM option, but will use it. I tried putting the " : " in front as you recommended, but it did not work, when I removed the " : " , it did work.